# sscanf changing the value of the sentence being parsed

Tags: c

Hi so I have the following code below

```
      pr->rdName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
      pr->rsName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
      pr->rtName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
      sscanf(pr->ASMInstruction, "mult\t%3s, %3s, %3s", pr->rdName, pr->rtName, pr->rsName);
```

Where `pr->ASMInstruction = "mult\t%3s, %3s, %3s";` but then become `` "\360e`" ``

No idea why this is happening. I tried running the code in it's own separate file and it worked fine. Any idea what could be causing this.

Note: Kept editing and it kinda seems that the pr->ASMInstruction is changing a some random spot.

Change the code to the following:

```
   ParseResult *pr = malloc(sizeof(ParseResult *));
   pr->ASMInstruction = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
   strcpy(pr->ASMInstruction, pASM);
   char *dummy = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(pASM));
   strcpy(dummy, pASM);
   char *token = strtok(dummy, " ");

   //char *command = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(pASM));

   pr->Mnemonic = "addi";

   if (strcmp(token, "addi") == 0)
   {
      pr->Mnemonic = "addi";
      pr->rdName = NULL;
      pr->rtName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
      pr->rsName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
      int ans = 0;

      sscanf(pASM, "addi\t%3s, %3s, %d", pr->rtName, pr->rsName, &ans);

      pr->Imm = ans;

      pr->rd = 255;
      pr->rt = nameToNumber(pr->rtName);
      pr->rs = nameToNumber(pr->rsName);

      pr->Opcode = "001000";
      pr->Funct = NULL;
      pr->RD = intToBinary(pr->rd, 4);
      pr->RS = intToBinary(pr->rs, 4);
      pr->RT = intToBinary(pr->rt, 4);
      pr->IMM = intToBinary(pr->Imm, 15);
   }
```

pr->ASMInstruction is still randomly changing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please see this page for instructions on how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .  Especially here, how is `pr` defined?

Comment: Sounds like a buffer overflow. This is what a debugger is good for finding. Put a data breakpoint on the `ASMInstruction` variable itself, and if it changes value then the breakpoint will trigger and you can debug the code that is trying to change `ASMInstruction`

Comment: `strcpy(dummy, pASM);` writes out of bounds, you did not allocate enough space

Comment: In addition to what MM said, `pr->ASMInstruction = calloc(100, sizeof(char)); strcpy(pr->ASMInstruction, pASM);` is also a buffer overflow waiting to happen, too. It is safer to use `strdup()` instead of `(m|c)alloc()`+`strcpy()`

Comment: `ParseResult *pr = malloc(sizeof(ParseResult *));` is invalid.

Comment: The malloc() of *dummy needs a +1 added to it . . . strlen() does not include the terminating null and strcpy() doesn't check the size of the output.  So as a minimum this one statement will cause a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. I did get this resolved. It was a buffer overflow. I realized I initialized the pr value incorrectly. It was supposed to be:

`ParseResult *pr = malloc(sizeof(ParseResult));`

Thank you!

Comment: To minimize the risk of allocating size for the wrong type, you should get in the habit of using `T *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` instead of `malloc(sizeof(T))`.